# How to place the list items horizontally in bootstrap cards(lists have to be placed dynamically i.e coming from the backend)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, angular-ui-bootstrap, horizontallist, bootstrap-cards

[image]I have created the bootstrap card and placed the lists coming from the backend but it is not showing properly(means the letters are coming one by one)

**dashboard.comonent.html**

```
 <li class="list-group-item" >
    <div class="row no-gutters">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="card-body">

          <p style="font-size: 23px;">  <i class="mdi mdi-battery-unknown menu-icon " ></i>
          </p><span id="jammer"
            style="color:white;"></span>

          <h5 class="card-text text-muted" style="font-size:15px;">Lat</h5>
          <h5 class="card-text text-muted" style="font-size:15px;"> Long 
          </h5>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="card-body">
          <p style="font-size: 23px;"> <i class="mdi mdi-battery-unknown menu-icon " ></i></p><span id="jammer"
          style="color:white;"></span>

        <h5 class="card-text text-muted" style="font-size:15px;">Lat</h5>
</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <div class="card-body">
          <p  style="font-size: 23px;"> <i class="mdi mdi-battery-unknown menu-icon " ></i></p>
        </div>
      </div>

</div>
  </li>


</ul>
```

Is there any other way to place the lists  horizontally and dynamic .

Can anyone help me regarding this.

Comment: "Letters are coming one by one" , Can you clarify this a bit, maybe post a MRE or image etc.

Comment: I have edited and   placed the image what I have got .The letters are coming one after another.

Comment: @Vipul Tawde Can you please help me for the above

Comment: oh it seems your letters are wrapping around because their containers don't have enough WIDTH. There are 2 ways to approach the issue. 1. increase the width of few of its containers and the letters will set themselves. 2. use word wrap properties to prevent breaking the words. for this i will post answer below.

Comment: also put border property on your divs containing text , it will help to realize why the text wraps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following css properties on the element or div containing the text.

```
word-break: break-all;
word-wrap: break-word;
overflow-wrap: break-word;
-webkit-hyphens: auto;
-moz-hyphens: auto;
-ms-hyphens: auto;
hyphens: auto;
```

Above code allows folding the words but not letters. if you dont want anything to wrap or fold to next line refer the different values for the above properties [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp).

```
white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Firefox */
white-space: -o-pre-wrap; /* Opera */
white-space: pre-wrap; /* Chrome */
word-wrap: break-word; /* IE */
```